# Force eager loading of otherwise lazy loaded properties

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I've got a Hibernate object which's properties are all loaded lazy. Most of these properties are other Hibernate objects or PersistentSets.

Now I want to force Hibernate to eager load these properties for just one time.

Of course I could "touch" each of these properties with `object.getSite().size()` but maybe there's another way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation puts it like this:

> You can force the usual eager fetching
>   of properties using `fetch all
>   properties` in HQL.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [19.1.7. Using lazy property fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties)

Answer (score 23):

This is an old question, but I also wanted to point out the static method `Hibernate.initialize`.

Example usage:

```
Person p = sess.createCriteria(Person.class, id);
Hibernate.initialize(p.getChildren());
```

The children are now initialized to be used even after the session is closed.

Answer (score 3):

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) works well for this type of thing - you can ask Dozer to map the object to another instance of the same class, and Dozer will visit all objects reachable from the current object.

See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182323/how-to-serialize-hibernate-collections-properly/182955#182955) and [my answer to another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183269/hibernate-and-serializable-entities/3183317#3183317) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

```
Person p = (Parent) sess.get(Person.class, id);
Hibernate.initialize(p.getChildren());
```

Rather than this:

```
Person p = sess.createCriteria(Person.class, id);
Hibernate.initialize(p.getChildren());
```

Answer (score 1):

**3 ways**

1.HQL with left join children

2.SetFetchMode after createCriteria

3.Hibernate.initialize

Answer (score 0):

This is slow, because it makes a round trip for every item it needs to initialize, but it gets the job done.

```
private void RecursiveInitialize(object o,IList completed)
{
    if (completed == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("completed");

    if (o == null) return;            

    if (completed.Contains(o)) return;            

    NHibernateUtil.Initialize(o);

    completed.Add(o);

    var type = NHibernateUtil.GetClass(o);

    if (type.IsSealed) return;

    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsArray)
        {
            var result = prop.GetValue(o, null) as IEnumerable;
            if (result == null) return;
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                RecursiveInitialize(item, completed);
            }
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
        {
            var result = prop.GetValue(o, null) as IEnumerable;
            if (result == null) return;
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                RecursiveInitialize(item, completed);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(o, null);
            RecursiveInitialize(value, completed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A decade has passed since this question was asked, but I bumped into this problem as well. I noticed that if you are using Spring, annotating the method with `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` solves it nicely.

Example

```
public void doThing(int id) {
 Thing thing = loadThing(id);
 Stuff stuff = thing.getLazyLoadedStuff();
}
```

doesn't work, exception thrown. But

```
@Transactional
public void doThing(int id) {
 Thing thing = loadThing(id);
 Stuff stuff = thing.getLazyLoadedStuff();
}
```

works.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html), you should be able to disable lazy property loading by setting the `lazy` attribute on your particular property mappings:

```
<class name="Document">
  <id name="id">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property length="50" name="name" not-null="true"/>
  <property lazy="false" length="200" name="summary" not-null="true"/>
  <property lazy="false" length="2000" name="text" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

Comment: I dont wan't to change the configuration, which is set lazy. I just want to achieve eager loading for one instance.